# dplyr conditional mutate on itself

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with a character variable consisting of mostly numeric values, with occasional known character strings as well as some `NA` values. I want to conditionally reformat the numeric values to have one decimal place, but leave the character and `NA` values alone.

This code works on a toy data frame and produces the desired output:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("1", "2", "3", "none", NA),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

test <- df %>%
  mutate(a = ifelse(is.na(a) | a == "none",
                    a,
                    format(round(as.numeric(a), 1), nsmall = 1)))

test
#    a
# 1  1.0
# 2  2.0
# 3  3.0
# 4 none
# 5 <NA>
```

But throws a warning message

```
Warning message:
In format(round(as.numeric(c("1", "2", "3", "none", NA)), 1), nsmall = 1) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

which I believe is the case b/c `format(round(as.numeric(a), 1), nsmall = 1)))` is still acting on the entire vector, even though the values from that are only used in the `mutate` statement where the `ifelse` condition is false.

I can wrap the whole thing in `suppressWarnings()`, but is there some other way to have this generate the desired output without warnings within the `dplyr` framework? I'm sure there's a `data.table` way to do it but this is part of a package that doesn't need `data.table` for anything else and it seems silly to make it necessary for such a small piece...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `replace` and you can convert just the numeric type data in column `a`:

```
test <- df %>%
    mutate(a = replace(a, !is.na(a) & a != "none",
                       format(round(as.numeric(a[!is.na(a) & a != "none"]), 1), nsmall = 1)))

test
#     a
#1  1.0
#2  2.0
#3  3.0
#4 none
#5 <NA>
```